# create file in another directory with php

Tags: php, file

My folder structure is like -

```
root
  admin
    create_page.php
  pages
    my_page1.php
    my_page2.php
```

I have code for creating a new php file in "pages" folder. the code is like -

```
$dir_path = "../pages/";
$ourFileName = '../'.$page_name.".txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$ourFileContent = '<?php echo "something..." ?>';
if (fwrite($ourFileHandle, $ourFileContent) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
    exit;
}
```

The code executes normally..no problem. but the page is not being created. please tell me what i am doing wrong. is there problem with the path?
    fclose($ourFileHandle);

Comment: You set '$dir_path', but your not using it. Also im not sure if you can use relative links, you might want to use the absolute path. Make sure you have set write permissions on the map writing to.

Comment: `$page_name` is not set and you didint write which file is it

Comment: where do you set `$page_name` also you have a syntax error on this line `<?php echo "something..." ?>` dont forget the closing semi-colon

Comment: And put `error_reporting(E_ALL)`  to see all warning and notices

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's an example using the more simpler [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) wrapper for fopen,fwrite,fclose

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$pagename = 'my_page1';

$newFileName = './pages/'.$pagename.".php";
$newFileContent = '<?php echo "something..."; ?>';

if (file_put_contents($newFileName, $newFileContent) !== false) {
    echo "File created (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
} else {
    echo "Cannot create file (" . basename($newFileName) . ")";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$ourFileHandle = fopen("../pages/" .$ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

Make the above change to the third line and it will probably work; I tried it and it worked.

Comment: In other words, to answer the original question, you can just put a path with the file you want to create.

Answer (score 2):

have you deliberately missed out on concatinating $dir_path and $ourFileName;

now

1. is your directory/file  [writable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php)?
2. check for your [current working directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)
3. is your error_reporting on ?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same Problem, File will not be created in a folder having different permission, make sure the permissions of the folders are same like other files.

Comment: You were right! I changed the permissions of the folder that i wanted to create the files in it with chmod 777, and fopen created the file properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$pagename = 'your_filename';
$newFileName = '../pages/'.$pagename.".php";
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.