# Possible to create a directory or subdomain?

Tags: php

Is it possible for my domain www.something.com to create a file or directory?

Topic : Affiliate link 
Scenario : www.something.com is a form page and after a client register , is it possible for the server or php to create a directory under the folder ref.
For example : www.something.com/ref/jay_awesome99
Is it possible to create it?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    if(isset($_POST['cid'],$_POST['gid']))
    {
        $cid = $_POST['cid'];
        $gid = $_POST['gid'];
        $new_link = "www.something.com/ref/".$cid."_".$gid ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you search something like that?: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mkdir.php

Comment: @Dinistro, but it will actually create a empty folder but is it possible to create a folder with a php file in it?

Comment: Try out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265274/php-create-and-save-a-txt-file-to-root-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible if you have write permission on this dir/server to create new dir under any directory
try with [mkdir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)
also if you want to create new file in this use file functions for this :-
[create file in another directory with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957485/create-file-in-another-directory-with-php)

Comment: but it will actually create a empty folder but is it possible to create a folder with a php file in it?

Answer (score 0):

For a php to make a directory, please check here :

[mkdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Please read more about it [here, + an example](http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=448) or [here](http://www.viiratech.com/tutorials/php-mysql/creating-a-folder.html)

To create a php file in a folder , [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411656/how-to-create-php-files-using-php)

Comment: but it will actually create a empty folder but is it possible to create a folder with a php file in it?

Comment: yes, first you create the folder, then you create the file in that folder